# Why does the verb "TO LIKE" have to take an object in "yes-or-no answers", when there is no chance of confusion?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, transitivity, grammar-myths

**A: Do you like coffee?**

**B: No I dont like. / Yes I like.**

We all know B's answer is wrong. Why? Because **"TO LIKE"** is a transitive verb and it needs an "**IT**" at the end. However, we all know that "without that "**IT**" at the end", the answer would still quite clear and wouldn't require an "**IT**" at all, because there is no possibility of getting confused about What B might be referring to. There is only one thing - **COFFEE**.

So, my question is "Why does **"TO LIKE"** have to be transitive when it does not have to be transitive? In other words, why does it have to take an object when it can function very well without being transitive in "yes or no questions".?

Comment: If a non-native English speaker were to tell you: **I go big shop buy coat** you would understand clearly what the person meant although the statement was not grammatical. You could form any number of similar ungrammatical statements the meaning of which was clear. Yours is simply an example of such.

Comment: A native speaker would just say "No, I don't." The only context in which I've occasionally heard "I don't like" is a rather curt response to "You can [do something] if you like."

Comment: @KateBunting, and that is a different meaning of _like_ (roughly "choose") which is intransitive.

Comment: Why does English (along with all European languages and some others) force you most of the time to choose whether you are talking about one or many? Why do Russian and other Slavonic languages require you to express the subject of a verb when the verb form often unambiguously specifies the subject? Why do many languages duplicate number gender and case marks redundantly on adjectives in a noun phrase? The answer, the **whole** answer, to all of these is "Because that's how it is". Sometimes it's possible to show the historical development, but that still doesn't answer "Why?"